# FIXED IT! Type 'ASP._Page__ViewStart_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.StartPage'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Moving and copying some files, now I have this exception on my project, used to work fine.

The thing is that this failing project is a copy of another one, that is working fine, so every critical file inside i´m sure it´s ok.

1. web.config --> from solution is ok.
2. web.config --> from views is ok.
3. viewStart --> ok.

I found out the fix for this, so if you have the same problem than me even if you did what other posts said about adding razor sections to the config, check this solution.

Regards!.

Answer (score 3):

Ok. So I´m assuming that you have all your configs ok, and all of the DLLs ok and updated.

If you did all of that and still having the exception, try to check and DOUBLE check if you don´t have any undesired "_viewStart" files placed somewhere wrong, and also check if is not excluded from solution.

In my case, this was the problem: I removed wrong "_viewStart" that I copied by mistake and the web start working again.

[image]
I´m sure that most of scenarios that everybody has this exception is caused by moving this file to another folder or creating a new one.

try it!
hope it helps.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks so much Yogurtu, this saved me a lot of time.